# Update a Field from results of other Field with muliple results

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have a *Field (Outcome)* that would produce the following results:

```
1.A 1.B 1.C etc
```

A second *Field (Payment)* would show the $ values:

```
1.A = $100 1.B = $150 1.C = $200
```

The 2 Fields are in a *Continuous Form (Payments Form)* and is based on a *Select Query (Customer_Completed Without Matching Payments)*

I have been playing with this and searching the net but have not found any obvious answers

Comment: You have described your setup, but it is not clear what you are looking to do.

Comment: Lee Thanks for the feedback.